# Data visualization using graphs (Display relationships between people, based on personality test)

Tags: graph, data-visualization

Hi I have a question regarding graph rendering. What type of graph would you use to display relationships based on a personality test between persons? Like this:
People can either like each other, dislike or feel neither good or bad against each other. 
Note here that if someone likes a person, it does not mean that that person likes him back, he could dislike him.

So this graph displays a minimum of 75 people and a maximum of 200.

So what type of graph would you use, and if possible are there any computer program that would help me render this grahp. (It would be positive if I myself could determine a picture that could be used to display each person, for example if the person in the graph is a woman then the "woman symbol" is displayed and vice versa for man)

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's kind of subjective how you display the relationships (go with "what is best" for the context you are displaying them in). But, here is a list of software:

- [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)
- [gephi](http://gephi.org/)
- [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)
- [pajek](http://pajek.imfm.si/doku.php)

Reviewing these should lead you to some examples of people with similar questions and the typical approaches they take for the visualisation of what you are interested in.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of this one here
http://www.kitware.com/news/files/205_EnronBundledGraph.png

But I think this is "doable" with the suggestions you have brought. So thank you so much for your help :)